# obtain or log the information set of lost or dropped packets between a source node and a destination node

Tags: omnet++, inet

How can we obtain or log the information set of lost or dropped packets between a source node S and a destination node D and also the cause of packet loss?
For example, we have written a scenario where the sender node S sends 1000 packets to the destination node D, but only 800 packets have been received at the destination. We want to get the information of those 200 packets along with the reason why they were not received at the destination.
Thanks